# Orthogonal connectors with non-overlapping horizontal or vertical line segments

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I have an upper row of $N$ equally spaced 'units' and a lower row of $N$ equally spaced 'units'. I would like to connect any of the upper row of units to the lower units via orthogonal connectors (consisting of horizonal and vertical line segments) such that although a horizontal and a vertical line segment, e.g. connecting $(3, 12)$ and $(4, 10)$, are allowed to intersect as shown below,

[image: Orthogonal connectors between row of equally spaced units]

a horizontal line segment may not overlap another another horizontal line segment, and vice versa for a vertical line segment, e.g. connecting $(9, 10)$ and $(8, 19)$ as shown below

[image: Orthogonal connectors between row of equally spaced units]

An acceptable connection between these units would look like this

[image: Orthogonal connectors between row of equally spaced units]

where the vertical line segments no longer overlap.

The only restriction is that each unit cannot 'support' more than one connection.

---

Here is the preferred solution to the *special case* of connectors between corresponding neighbouring upper and lower units e.g. $(0, 11)$ and $(1, 10)$

[image: Orthogonal connectors between row of equally spaced units]

Comment: What is the question? Are you simply looking for an arrangement of non-overlapping wires?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes, that's what I am looking for. Please note that wires may cross each other but cannot lie on top of each other.

Comment: The connections are $(9,10)$ and $(8,19)$. I will upload what a proper layout for this case ought to look like.

Comment: Yes they can. Any upper unit can be connected to any lower unit in any permutation. The only restriction is that one unit cannot support more than one connection.

Comment: This is not always possible. Just think of $0\to11, 1\to10$.

Comment: In theory there are infinite however I'd like to have as few points as possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $(0, 11), (1, 10)$ is a _special case_. I'll add a graphic showing a preferred solution to it.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Can you please post your previous solution as a comment if it is still valid in the non-special case. I'd like to explore it. Thank you.

Comment: @Olumide: there are more complex cases that are also impossible.

Comment: Must wires be "grid-aligned"?  Can you have multiple verticle lines/wires per component?  Is there a limit on the number of horizontal rows/lines/writes that can fit between the lower unit and the upper unit?

Comment: @D.W. Yes the wires must be grid aligned, i.e. orthogonal. Only one wire can come out of a component. No there is no limit of horizontal rows that can fit between the upper and lower rows of units, but fewer is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the upper row units be denoted by $u_1, \dotsc, u_N$ and lower row units be denoted by $\ell_1, \dotsc, \ell_N$. You can divide the region between the upper and lower rows into a grid $G$ of size $2N \times 2N$. For connecting $u_i$ to $\ell_j$ simply choose the path $G[1,2i]$  -> $G[2i,2i]$ ->  $G[2i,2j-1]$  ->  $G[2N,2j-1]$ (assuming $1$ based indexing).

Next, we show that for any two pairs $(u_i,\ell_j)$ and $(u_p,\ell_q)$ such that $i \neq p$ and $j \neq q$, the connections do not overlap.

*Proof*: Note that the horizontal line segment for connection between $u_i$ and $\ell_j$ uses row number $2i$ which is different from the row number $2p$, which is used by connection between $u_p$ and $\ell_q$ since $i \neq p$.

The vertical line segments uses the columns $2i$, $2j-1$, $2p$, and $2q-1$. Since an even numbered and odd numbered column can never overlap, we just need to check if $2i$ overlaps with $2p$ or $2j-1$ overlaps with $2q-1$. Since $i \neq p$ and $j \neq q$, overlapping is not possible.

Comment: I think I see what you did. The connectors start at even indexes (on the upper row) and end on odd indexes (on the lower row), and prevents overlapping of line segments by mandating them to travel on different indexes. This solution does satisfy the **unspoken** wishlist of (1) centring the connectors on the units or (2) allowing the two line segments to travel along the same index, where possible. The latter desirable would make this a search problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Olumide I did not understand this part: "The latter desirable would make this a search problem."

Comment: I meant to say that satisfying #2 of the unspoken wishlist would involve some sort of combinatorial search wouldn't it? BTW, what topic of CS does your solution belong to?

Comment: @Olumide Yeah. Maybe. Umm it is not a specific topic of CS. I guess computational geometry would be the closest.

Comment: Would you be open to a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146946/orthogonal-connectors?tab=generalhttps://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146946/orthogonal-connectors?tab=general) conversation?